# When running the application it duplicates the database rows (around 5 times)

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

This is currently a test application links to a test database.  The database currently has 5 records and is stored in Access (accdb format).  When open the Solution in Visual Studio (not running), it duplicate the existing rows (Total 35 rows).  If I close the solutions and open it again, I then have 155 rows and so on.

MainWindows.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <!--create an instance of our DataProvider class-->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CustomerDataProvider"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type local:CustomerDataProvider}"/>
    <!--define the method which is invoked to obtain our data-->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Customer"
                        ObjectInstance="{StaticResource 
CustomerDataProvider}"
                        MethodName="GetCustomers"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Customer}}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid" />
</DockPanel>
</Window>
Class
using System.Data;
using WpfApp1.Database5DataSetTableAdapters;

namespace WpfApp1
{
public class Database5Provider
{
    private static Database5DataSet database5DataSet;

    public static Database5DataSet Database5DataSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (database5DataSet == null)
            {
                database5DataSet = new Database5DataSet();
            }
            return Database5Provider.database5DataSet;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerDataProvider
{
    private CustomerTableAdapter adapter;

    // private Database5DataSet dataset; 

    public CustomerDataProvider()
    {
        Database5DataSet dataset = Database5Provider.Database5DataSet;

        adapter = new CustomerTableAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(Database5Provider.Database5DataSet.Customer);

        dataset.Customer.CustomerRowChanged += new Database5DataSet.CustomerRowChangeEventHandler(CustomerRowModified);
        dataset.Customer.CustomerRowDeleted += new Database5DataSet.CustomerRowChangeEventHandler(CustomerRowModified);
    }


    void CustomerRowModified(object sender, Database5DataSet.CustomerRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        adapter.Update(Database5Provider.Database5DataSet.Customer);
    }

    public DataView GetCustomers()
    {
        return Database5Provider.Database5DataSet.Customer.DefaultView;
    }
}
}
```

I can see the duplication happens when the MainWindows.xaml design view loads.  While its saying "Loading designer... You can continue working while the designer is loading in the background." no duplication has happened.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Is this CustomerDataProvider object created when this window is initialized or is an existing object?

Comment: I am following this guide https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples    I think the datagrid is running the function GetCustomers() and this is causing the duplication.

Comment: I can also see that the Row ID keep increasing, even if I delete the rows in the access database.  The Row ID is now 185711

Comment: As far as i can tell (it's a very long article and i don't really want to read it all at the moment) it seems that in some way you are storing this data in your memory. I have absolutely no clue on how this work, but consider that this article was written 8 years ago (when datagrid were introduced). so i would honstly go for another approach

Comment: In your database you have still 5 rows?

Comment: That keeps expanding when I run my app but at the moment I only have 5 rows.

Comment: I am planning to build an application that feed of an accdb file with multiple tables.  I want people to be able to edit these tables from the app.

Comment: You need to check how many rows contain your Dataset, and that when you call a new CustomerTableAdapter this is empty before doing the Fill operation

Comment: So the Fill operation is adding to the existing CustomerTableAdapter causing the duplications?

Comment: I think so. If i understand right, CustomerTableAdapter  role is to get the data read from your db. It shouldn't store previous iteration, cause you have already a Database that store your data. CustomerTableAdapter   is just a class that must created everytime you are going to use your app and that it must be filled one time reading from your DB

Comment: I will have another go at the solution later tonight.  Thank you for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi,  For those interested in the outcome.  The cause of this was due to me not having a Primary key in my database.